# Transferring Xbox 360 games to playstation

Tags: xbox-360

If you save a game on a flash drive for xbox, can you transfer it to a playstation ?

Answer (score 4):

No.

Playstation can neither interpret the Xbox file format, nor its data structure for saving game data.

Furthermore, Xbox games are not compatible with PlayStation.